# Python jsonpath Filter Expression

Tags: python, jsonpath

**Background:**

I have the following example data structure in JSON:

```
{'sensor' : [
    {'assertions_enabled': 'ucr+',
     'deassertions_enabled': 'ucr+',
     'entity_id': '7.0',
     'lower_critical': 'na',
     'lower_non_critical': 'na',
     'lower_non_recoverable': 'na',
     'reading_type': 'analog',
     'sensor_id': 'SR5680 TEMP (0x5d)',
     'sensor_reading': {'confidence_interval': '0.500',
                    'units': 'degrees C',
                    'value': '42'},
     'sensor_type': 'Temperature',
     'status': 'ok',
     'upper_critical': '59.000',
     'upper_non_critical': 'na',
     'upper_non_recoverable': 'na'}
]}
```

The sensor list will actually contain many of these dicts containing sensor info.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to query the list using jsonpath to return me a subset of sensor dicts that have `sensor_type=='Temperature'` but I'm getting `'False'` returned (no match).  Here's my jsonpath expression:

```
results = jsonpath.jsonpath(ipmi_node, "$.sensor[?(@.['sensor_type']=='Temperature')]")
```

When I remove the filter expression and just use `"$.sensor.*"` I get a list of all sensors, so I'm sure the problem is in the filter expression.

I've scanned multiple sites/posts for examples and I can't seem to find anything specific to Python (Javascript and PHP seem to be more prominent).  Could anyone offer some guidance please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following expression does what you need (notice how the attribute is specified):

```
jsonpath.jsonpath(impi_node, "$.sensor[?(@.sensor_type=='Temperature')]")
```

Comment: Actually, what ended up working for me is removing the '.' in @.['sensor_type'].  Apparently it's just @['sensor_type'].

Comment: The two forms are probably valid.

Comment: where did you find "jsonpath", there are no links here it seems
https://pypi.python.org/simple/jsonpath/ ?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath/. It seems to be unmaintained though :(... You're probably better off looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

I am using [jsonpath-ng](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng) which seems to be active (as of 23.11.20) and I provide solution based on to Pedro's jsonpath expression:

```
data = {
    'sensor' : [
        {'sensor_type': 'Temperature', 'id': '1'},
        {'sensor_type': 'Humidity'   , 'id': '2'},
        {'sensor_type': 'Temperature', 'id': '3'},
        {'sensor_type': 'Density'    , 'id': '4'}
    ]} 

from jsonpath_ng.ext import parser
for match in parser.parse("$.sensor[?(@.sensor_type=='Temperature')]").find(data):
    print(match.value)
```

Output:

```
{'sensor_type': 'Temperature', 'id': '1'}
{'sensor_type': 'Temperature', 'id': '3'}
```

NOTE: besides basic documentation provided on project's homepage I found additional information in [tests](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/blob/master/tests/test_jsonpath_rw_ext.py).