# How to extract specific nested JSON value doing loop? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```html
{
   "127.0.0.1":{
      "addresses":{
         "ipv4":"127.0.0.1"
      },
      "hostnames":[
         {
            "name":"localhost",
            "type":"PTR"
         }
      ],
      "status":{
         "reason":"conn-refused",
         "state":"up"
      },
      "tcp":{
         "5000":{
            "conf":"10",
            "cpe":"cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2",
            "extrainfo":"Python 3.9.2",
            "name":"http",
            "product":"Werkzeug httpd",
            "reason":"syn-ack",
            "script":{
               "vulners":"\n  cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2: \n    \tCVE-2021-29921\t7.5\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-29921\n    \tCVE-2021-23336\t4.0\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-23336\n    \tMSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/metasploit/MSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t*EXPLOIT*\n    \tCVE-2021-3426\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-3426"
            },
            "state":"open",
            "version":"1.0.1"
         },
         "6000":{
            "conf":"10",
            "cpe":"cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2",
            "extrainfo":"Python 3.9.2",
            "name":"http",
            "product":"Werkzeug httpd",
            "reason":"syn-ack",
            "script":{
               "vulners":"\n  cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2: \n    \tCVE-2021-29921\t7.5\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-29921\n    \tCVE-2021-23336\t4.0\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-23336\n    \tMSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/metasploit/MSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t*EXPLOIT*\n    \tCVE-2021-3426\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-3426"
            },
            "state":"open",
            "version":"1.0.1"
         }
      },
      "vendor":{
         
      }
   }
}
```

I want to extract "vulners" value here i tried this -

```
    results = []
for x in collection.find({},{"scan": 1, "_id": 0 }):
    results.append(json.loads(json_util.dumps(x)))

portnumber = []
datay = []
datapro = []


for result in results:
    ips = result['scan']


for ip in ips:

        ports = result['scan'][ip]['tcp']
        ipdomain = result['scan'][ip]['hostnames']

        for ip2 in ipdomain:
            ip3 = ip2['name']

        for port in ports:
            portnumber.append(port)
            datax = ports[port]['script']
            datay.append(datax)
            datapro2 = ports[port]['product']
            datapro.append(datapro2)
            date = datetime.datetime.now()
            date_now = date.strftime("%x, %X")

        pass_json_var = {'domain': ip3, 'ports': portnumber, 'product': datapro, 'vulnerabilities': datay, "date": date_now}

        if isinstance(pass_json_var, list):
            domaindata.insert_many(pass_json_var)
        else:
            domaindata.insert_one(pass_json_var)
```

Ok so here if the "results" output gives me one "vulners" value then it works fine but when it's multiple ports with vulners values it doesn't work!

How can i access the 'vulners' value? Hoping for someone to guide me also a bit, Please try to give a solution which is dynamic

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is your port variable a number? because that might be messing it up

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code snippet. Also post minimal reproducible example, e.g. what is `collections`? Also not sure why you need to `json_util` dump and immediately json load, but I guess it is irrelevant to your question anyway. The JSON you show has no key `scan`, what do you expect from `result['scan']`?

Comment: Im trying to go step by step and trying to access the nested json value as you can see but Its not working

Comment: If you want to add a solution, use the answer section. If one of the existing answers solved it, then you can mark that as accepted. Please do not edit the solution into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

```py
def extract_data(ip_address_data):
    domains = ip_address_data["hostnames"]
    ports_data = []
    # Each port can have different products and vulners
    # So that data is grouped together in a dictionary
    for port in ip_address_data["tcp"].keys():
        port_data = ip_address_data["tcp"][port]
        product = port_data["product"]
        vulners = port_data['script']['vulners']
        ports_data.append({
            "port": port,
            "product": product,
            "vulners": vulners
        })

    return {
        "domains": domains,
        "ports_data": ports_data
    }

# Result is the data from mongo db
# result = collection.find({})["scan"]
result = {
    "127.0.0.1": {
        "addresses": {
            "ipv4": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "hostnames": [
            {
                "name": "localhost",
                "type": "PTR"
            }
        ],
        "status": {
            "reason": "conn-refused",
            "state": "up"
        },
        "tcp": {
            "5000": {
                "conf": "10",
                "cpe": "cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2",
                "extrainfo": "Python 3.9.2",
                "name": "http",
                "product": "Werkzeug httpd",
                "reason": "syn-ack",
                "script": {
                    "vulners": "\n  cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2: \n    \tCVE-2021-29921\t7.5\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-29921\n    \tCVE-2021-23336\t4.0\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-23336\n    \tMSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/metasploit/MSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t*EXPLOIT*\n    \tCVE-2021-3426\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-3426"
                },
                "state": "open",
                "version": "1.0.1"
            },
            "6000": {
                "conf": "10",
                "cpe": "cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2",
                "extrainfo": "Python 3.9.2",
                "name": "http",
                "product": "Werkzeug httpd",
                "reason": "syn-ack",
                "script": {
                    "vulners": "\n  cpe:/a:python:python:3.9.2: \n    \tCVE-2021-29921\t7.5\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-29921\n    \tCVE-2021-23336\t4.0\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-23336\n    \tMSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/metasploit/MSF:ILITIES/DEBIAN-CVE-2021-3426/\t*EXPLOIT*\n    \tCVE-2021-3426\t2.7\thttps://vulners.com/cve/CVE-2021-3426"
                },
                "state": "open",
                "version": "1.0.1"
            }
        },
        "vendor": {

        }
    }
}


def scandata():
    for ip_address in result:
        ip_address_data = extract_data(
            result[ip_address]
        )

        print(ip_address, ip_address_data)


scandata()
```

Comment: Can we directly access     `domains = result["hostnames"]` ? Don't we need a loop to go there? 

Like this?

```
for result in results:
    ips = result['scan']
```

Comment: No we can't use it directly.  
The `result` variable in your code is not the same as the one used in the solution.
The `result` variable in the `extract_data` function is in the form `{"domains":"...","addresses":"...",...`} while in your code it is in the form `{"35.0.0.0.0": {"domains:"...",...}`.

The `result` variable in the solution is got after `DataSourceDictionary[ip_address]` in the `scandata` function.

You can use the `for ip_address in collection.find({})["scan"]:` in the `scandata` function to get data directly from mongodb

Comment: I have updated my JSON  , actually my current code works but only if there is one port with vulners value so if there are multiple ports with that value it wont work! Can you check my updated question'? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Updated the answer to be more adaptable

Comment: actually solution is working but its not giving a valid json output

Comment: `@app.route('/api/vulnerableports', methods=['GET'])
def extract_data(ip_address_data):
    domains = ip_address_data["hostnames"]
    ports_data = []`

This actually throws an error because ip_address_data should be a passed URL variable in terms of flask, How can i do this in flask without putting it inside the function?

Comment: [Working Example](https://gist.github.com/AntonioMande/c67d96bb6330a717f8489558cc40e342), i would recommend to first get more comfortable with program flow and basic data structures in python, because after that, you would be able to resolve most issues and progress much faster @Jevin

Answer (score 1):

**Model based approach**

this approach is based on a model of your data you want to parse. From my point of view this is more work in the beginning. With the advantage, that you will have clean error messages and you can control the behaviour by adapting your data model.

1. make a model of the data you want to parse

```
from typing import Any, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class ExScript(BaseModel):
    vulners:str = ""

class Ex30000(BaseModel):
    script:ExScript = Field(default=Any)
        
class ExTcp(BaseModel):
    root:Ex30000= Field(default=Any, alias="30000")
    
class ExRoot(BaseModel):
    tcp:ExTcp = Field() # Required
    
class Base(BaseModel):
    root:ExRoot = Field(default=Any, alias="35.0.0.0.0")
```

2. change your input data to a raw string outherwise you will have to escape \n and \t

```
input_will_work = r"""{
  "35.0.0.0.0": {
    "hostnames": [
      {
        "name": "domain.com",
        "type": "PTR"
      }
    ],
    "addresses": {
      "ipv4": "35.0.0.0"
    },
    "vendor": {},
    "status": {
      "state": "up",
      "reason": "syn-ack"
    },
    "tcp": {
      "30000": {
        "state": "open",
        "reason": "syn-ack",
        "name": "http",
        "product": "nginx",
        "version": "1.20.0",
        "extrainfo": "",
        "conf": "10",
        "cpe": "cpe:/a:igor_sysoev:nginx:1.20.0",
        "script": {
          "http-server-header": "nginx/1.20.0",
          "vulners": "\n  cpe:/a:igor_sysoev:nginx:1.20.0: \n    \tNGINX:CVE-2021-23017\t6.8\thttps://vulners.com/nginx/NGINX:CVE-2021-23017\n    \t9A14990B-D52A-56B6-966C-6F35C8B8EB9D\t6.8\thttps://vulners.com/githubexploit/9A14990B-D52A-56B6-966C-6F35C8B8EB9D\t*EXPLOIT*\n    \t1337DAY-ID-36300\t6.8\thttps://vulners.com/zdt/1337DAY-ID-36300\t*EXPLOIT*\n    \tPACKETSTORM:162830\t0.0\thttps://vulners.com/packetstorm/PACKETSTORM:162830\t*EXPLOIT*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

input_will_fail = r"""{
  "35.0.0.0.0": {}
}
"""
```

3.1 this should give you the expected result

```
obj1 = Base.parse_raw(input_will_work)
print(obj1.root.tcp.root.script.vulners)
```

3.2 this should throw an exception

```
obj2 = Base.parse_raw(input_will_fail)
```

**Search data with jsonpath**

should return all objects with the name **vulners**

```
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse
import json

obj = json.loads(input_will_work)
p = parse('$..vulners')
      
for match in p.find(obj):
    print(match.value)
```

Comment: This looks more hardcoded, I need a solution that goes with MongoDB queries actually.

Comment: with jsonpath you can write more general queries against your data. It works similar to xpath for xml documents. [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343282/python-jsonpath-filter-expression).

Comment: added an example for jsonpath. If you want I can make a new answere out of it.

Comment: Yes it would be great!

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works! but I'm trying to do this in flask

`    for match in p.find(obj):
        return jsonify(match.value) ` so this line actually giving me error

Answer (score 0):

```
        def extract_data(ip_address_data):
    domains = ip_address_data["hostnames"]
    ports_data = []
    # Each port can have different products and vulners
    # So that data is grouped together in a dictionary
    for port in ip_address_data["tcp"].keys():
        port_data = ip_address_data["tcp"][port]
        product = port_data["product"]
        vulners = port_data['script']['vulners']
        ports_data.append({
            "port": port,
            "product": product,
            "vulners": vulners
        })

    return {
        "domains": domains,
        "ports_data": ports_data
    }




@app.route('/api/vulnerableports', methods=['GET'])
def show_vulnerableports():
    data = []
    resultz = []


    for x in collection.find({}, {"scan": 1, "_id": 0}):
        resultz.append(json.loads(json_util.dumps(x)))

    for resultx in resultz:
        result = resultx['scan']

    for ip_address in result:
        ip_address_data = extract_data(
            result[ip_address]
        )
        data.append({ip_address: ip_address_data})

    return jsonify(data)
```

So this is the solution! i had to iterate over script and then access vulner!